# MDX to filter on a specific hiearachy and move (lag) on another hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I've some trouble with MDX to filter on a specific hiearachy and move (lag) on another hierarchy.

I've a dimension FinancialYear with 2 attributes :

```
Year (2014,2015,2016,2017,2018) 
Active (yes,no)
```

Here are the underlaying datas :

```
year/active
2014:no
2015:no
2016:yes
2017:no
2018:no
```

I would like to create a set with the previous year of the active yes. --> I want 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code must be the way to go:

```
{[FinancialYear].[Year].[Year].Members * [FinancialYear].[Active].&[yes]}.Item(0).Item(0).Lag(1)
```

Comment: (upped) I like that